# C# create an image that follows the mouse

Tags: c#, image, winforms, mouse

I'm trying to create a program within winForm in C# where an image will follow the mouse outside the application.

I have no clue how to draw an image outside of the form, let alone have it follow the mouse. My solution was going to be - create a borderless form and have the it follow the mouse - but this solution will not work because I cannot move a form via code.

The mouse needs to be able to click and function independently from this image.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can't you use custom mouse cursor instead of writing app for that?

Comment: check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162433/how-to-drag-and-move-winform-using-mouse

seems you want to do something like this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I cannot, because this will be used with touch simulation input so the user know where they are touching.

Comment: Rohit, that thread does not help me and is not what I want to do. Thank you though. The image that follow cannot affect the usage or clicks of the mouse.

Comment: why can't move a form via code? `Form.Location??`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it must do so without changing the way the mouse is used.

Set WS_EX_TRANSPARENT for the extended styles to make your form ignore mouse clicks.  Set TopMost to True and Opacity to something less than 100% to make it semi-transparent.  Move your form with a Timer.  Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = .5;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

        // Makes the form circular:
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath GP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        GP.AddEllipse(this.ClientRectangle);
        this.Region = new Region(GP);
    }

    const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = Cursor.Position;
        pt.Offset(-1 * this.Width / 2, -1 * this.Height / 2);
        this.Location = pt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

check this thread :

[How to drag and move winform using mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162433/how-to-drag-and-move-winform-using-mouse)

seems you want to do something like this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, this is not what I want to do. I don't appreciate the vote down either. I specifically said that the movement of the image cannot affect the usage of the mouse, and it must move naturally. Like if I want to create a program that has a magnifier image follow the mouse, it must do so without changing the way the mouse is used. Thank you for your input though, it is much appreciated.

Comment: No, Sorry for not being too clear in my original message. In my program I'm simulation touch input, and need an image to follow where the fingers are (using a depth camera) so I basically need to draw an overlay image on the screen that wont affect anything, and just serve so the user knows where their fingers are.